# JS - horizontal scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scrollbar

Trying to make horizontal scroll on some list but I get error - ''Uncaught TypeError: $(...).mousewheel is not a function''.
My JS is:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.item-list').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
    this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
    e.preventDefault();
});

});

</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='/wp-content/themes/engrave-lite-child/js/jquery.mousewheel.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Add the `jquery.mousewheel.js` `<script>` tag after the `jquery.min.js` one

Comment: yea right, its working now thanks @JacobGray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `jquery.mousewheel.js` source file *after* the jQuery source:

```css
.item-list {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.i-con {
  width: 3000px;
  background: orange;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-mousewheel/3.1.13/jquery.mousewheel.min.js'></script>

<div class="item-list">
  <div class="i-con"></div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.item-list').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
      this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
      e.preventDefault();
    });

  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `mousewheel()` before you load the library!
you should put your custom script tag after the library.

You can also (not mandatory) defer the load of the library by calling it from inside the dom ready and init in callback when you know it is loaded for sure:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get('/wp-content/themes/engrave-lite-child/js/jquery.mousewheel.js', function(){
        $('.item-list').mousewheel(function(e, delta) {
            this.scrollLeft -= (delta * 40);
            e.preventDefault();
        });
    });
});
```